# Why are all linear maps on $\mathbb{R}^d$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $W$ is a normed space and $A : \mathbb{R}^d \to W$ is a linear operator. Why is $A$ automatically bounded?

Comment: Because it is bounded on a base (for finitely many numbers we always have the ir max) and for the rest "interpolate" between base vectors

Comment: Maybe that's clear to you but a comment on terminology may be in order. Usually a map $f:X\rightarrow V$ is called bounded iff $\sup_X |f|\le C$ for some constant $C>0$. In case of linear operators a different definition applies: a linear operator $A$ is called bounded, if it satisfies an inequality $|Ax| \le C |x|$, which is equivalent to saying it's bounded (in the previous sense) on the unit ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every norm on $R^d$ are equivalent, thus you can suppose that the norm is $\|x\|=\sup_{i=1,..,n} \mid x_i\mid$ where $x_i$ are the coordinates of $x$ in the basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$. You have $\|A(x)\|\leq \mid x_1\mid \|A(e_1)\|+...+\mid x_n\mid \|A(e_n)\|\leq sup \mid x_i\mid_{i=1,..n} sup_{j=1,..n}\|A(e_j)\|\leq Sup_{j=1,..,n}\|A(e_j)\|\|x\|$.